# Responsive images reflow

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

We are developing a responsive site where we allow a user to upload images.

We preserve the original and then generate a thumbnail image to be served to users with lower resolutions.

The issue that has been raised is that when the image is switched in the logic for the smaller screen size there is a visible re-flow of the elements around it.

I am unsure how to prevent this as the images are of inconsistent height so cannot set an initial height on the containing element.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

I looked at this:

http://andmag.se/2012/10/responsive-images-how-to-prevent-reflow/

But it seems to be only for scenarios where we know the ratio i.e. 16:9, 4:3 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your thumbnails have a fixed maximum size.

You can put your image inside a box with the maximum height/width set so the orientations (landscape, portrait, square) doesn't matter. This would give you fixed whitespace around your image.

You can also generate this whitespace in the thumbnail giving you a fixed width/height in all your images.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes that is about the best we could come up with.